# python inheritance of class that have init argument

Tags: python, class, inheritance, init

```
class Salary:
    def __init__(self, basic_salary_table):
        self.basic_salary_table = basic_salary_table
        pass

    def basic_salary(self):
        if self.grade == 0:
            if self.level > 50:
                return int(self.basic_salary_table[3][self.basic_salary_table[3]['level']==50]['basic_salary'])
            return int(self.basic_salary_table[3][self.basic_salary_table[3]['level']==self.level]['basic_salary'])
        else:
            self.grade = str(self.grade)+'grade'
            return int(self.basic_salary_table[0][self.basic_salary_table[0]['level']==self.level][self.grade])

class Person(Salary):
    def __init__(self, name, id, job, level, grade=0):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.job = job
        self.level = level
        self.grade = grade
```

when i create Person object as person1 then call person1.basic_salary()
interpreter says, 'Person' object has no attribute 'basic_salary_table'

Comment: You haven't called `Salary__init__()` from `Person.__init__`, so of course anything defined by `Salary.__init__` hasn't been defined on your `Person` instance.

Comment: And I don't know how can do so, since you don't pass `basic_salary_table` to the `Person` constructor.  Where is that supposed to come from?  Is it a global?

Comment: Generally, you'd pass it to `Person` constructor, but it could reasonably be a global.

Comment: Your inheritance is kind of weird, though; a person is generally not considered a salary.

Comment: you mean, i should include `basic_salary_table` for each object of Person, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute `super().__init__` method in `__init__` method of subclass.

[`object.__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__setattr__#object.__init__)

> Called after the instance has been created (by __new__()), but before it is returned to the caller. The arguments are those passed to the class constructor expression. If a base class has an __init__() method, the derived class’s __init__() method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper initialization of the base class part of the instance; for example: `super().__init__([args...])`.

Like this:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.b = b
        super().__init__(a)


B(1, 2).print_a()

# 1
```